# How to set GWT Class field from JSNI on Javascript event

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have this GWT Class that wrapped the [Shephered Tour](https://github.com/HubSpot/shepherd) Javascript library:

```
public class SheperedTour {
    private static boolean started = false;
    private static boolean finished = false;
    private static JavaScriptObject tour;

    public static void startTour(){
        if(!started){
            _startTour();
            started = true;
        }
    }       
    public static native void cancelTour()/*-{
        @com.mycomp.app.client.local.utils.SheperedTour::tour.cancel();
    }-*/;

    public static native void _startTour()/*-{
        tour = new $wnd.Shepherd.Tour({
            defaults: {
                classes: 'shepherd-theme-arrows'
            }
        });
        @com.mycomp.app.client.local.utils.SheperedTour::tour = tour;
        tour.addStep('tour-6', {
            text: 'When done, click this to submit',
            attachTo: '#submit left',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Finish',
                    action: tour.next
                }
            ]
        });
        tour.start();
    }-*/;
}
```

What I need to accomplish is to set the `finished` static field, when the 'Finish' button is clicked. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of "Finish" button call a Java Method from JavaScript(JSNI) which set finished static field

```
[instance-expr.]@class-name::field-name//Syntax
```